# Is it possible to prevent certain content from being crawled (i.e. SEO) but still allow spam-bots/scrapers to see it?

Tags: seo, spam-prevention

This is a "very" special use case. But lets say we have the following:

I have a webpage, www.myportfolio.com, and inside of it I want to list several emails like so:

```
<p class="email1">john.doe@gmail.com<p>
```

By adding this content, I will be affecting the SEO of the page. But that is the issue, I do NOT wanna have this content affect the page's SEO rankings. BUT I do want spammers and page scrapers to be able to read this content anyway. So, ultimately,

**Is it possible to tell Googlebot (and other bots) to not crawl this sub-content but to still crawl the rest of the page?**

And please provide some reputable sources for your answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In short No, not in the purest sense.  You can tell Google/Bing/Yahoo/etc to exclude a site, a directory, or a page using robots.txt, you can do a page-level exclude using "no index" tags, but not a section.

What you can do, is put the offending content on another source page, and pull it into your main page via an iframe, and just block the source page with robots or "no index" meta (`<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">`).